# Can't insert text into CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

I am trying to insert text into CKEditor and looks like it's not working.

```
<textarea name="editor2" class="form-control" id="announcementEditBody" rows="3" placeholder="Enter ..."></textarea>

CKEDITOR.replace('editor2');

 $('editor2').val(response['aBody']);
```

Neither does CKEDITOR.instances.editor2.setData(); work, neither .insertText neither ['editor2'], it gives me this error `Unable to get property 'setData' of undefined or null reference`.

Answer (score 0):

In CKEditor documentation they wrote about use of ID, so try to set data this way -

```
CKEDITOR.instances.announcementEditBody.setData();
```

OR

```
CKEDITOR.instances['announcementEditBody'].setData();
```

Comment: `Unable to get property 'setData' of undefined or null reference`

Comment: Error means that you are trying to call `setData()` on `undefined` property. CKEditor instance named `editor2` doesn't exist. Please open dev-tools in Firefox or Chrome, switch to console and type `CKEDITOR.instances.` and you should get name or names of editor instances which are available.